# List<T> joins DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, model-view-controller, datatable

I have a List of objects (lst) and DataTable (dt). I want to join the lst and dt on the common field (code as string) and need to return all matching rows in the lst.

My List contains two columns i.e code and name along with values below:

```
code name
==== ====    
1    x    
2    y    
3    z
```

The DataTable contains two columns i.e code and value along with values below:

```
code value
==== =====    
3    a    
4    b    
5    c
```

The result is:

```
3   z
```

Below is my code; but I know it is not a correct statement and thus seeking your advice here. I would be much appreciated if you could guide me on how to write the correct statement.

```
var ld = from l in lst
         join d in dt.AsEnumerable() on l.code equals d.code
         select new { l.code, l.name };
```

Comment: `equals d.Field<int>("code")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Linq query or Join extension method to join the collection on code. Just that when you select data from datatable, you need to use dt.Field method. Please use either of the following code.

**Query1:**

```
var ld = lst.Join(dt.AsEnumerable(),
            l => l.code,
            d => d.Field<string>("code"),
            (l, d) => new
            {
                l.code,
                l.name,
                value = d.Field<string>("value")
            }).ToList();
```

**Query2:**

```
var ld = (from l in lst
          join d in dt.AsEnumerable()
          on l.code equals d.Field<string>("code")
          select new
          {
              l.code,
              l.name,
              value = d.Field<string>("value")
          }).ToList();
```

**Query3:**

```
var ld = (from l in lst
          join d in dt.AsEnumerable()
          on l.code equals d.Field<string>("code")
          let value = d.Field<string>("value")
          select new
          {
              l.code,
              l.name,
              value
          }).ToList();
```

Comment: Dear Ayaz, your solution works flawlessly. Thanks so much for your help. Question, why it does not recognize when we select new { l.code, l.name, d.Field<string>("value") }

and it accepts only when you assign d=Field<string>("value") and then perform select new { l.code, l.name, value = d.Field<string>("value") } instead?

Comment: It does recognize d.Field<string>("value") but it complains about the property name. Since anonymous type is returned from select new { ..... }, it expects the property name to be defined. For other two code and name, it just takes as it is. It is optional to define the property name for code and name but value is evaluated as expression so we need to explicitly set the property name.

Comment: You can move the d.Field<string>("value") out of anonymous type and use directly value. Please check the answer. I have added Query#3.

Comment: Thanks for your answering my question-- much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can try any of the below.

```
var ld = from l in lst
     join d in dt.AsEnumerable() on l.code equals d.Field<int>("code")
     select new { l.code, l.name };

var ld = lst.Join(dt.AsEnumerable(), l => l.code, d => d.Field<int>("code"), (l,d) => new { l.code, l.name });
```

Comment: Dear Sarwar, thanks for providing your solution. I tried to run your code and print the result of the query and it returned like this:

1 : x
2 : y
3 : z

it supposes to print 3 : z

Comment: List<CodeName> lst = new List<CodeName>();
            lst.Add(new CodeName { code = "1", name = "x" });
            lst.Add(new CodeName { code = "2", name = "y" });
            lst.Add(new CodeName { code = "3", name = "z" });

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("code", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("value", typeof(string));
            dt.Rows.Add("1", "a");
            dt.Rows.Add("2", "b");
            dt.Rows.Add("3", "c");

Comment: var ld = from l in lst
                     join d in dt.AsEnumerable() on l.code equals d.Field<string>("code")
                     select new { l.code, l.name };

Comment: It seems, you are not adding the correct data in DataTable. In the question, you have mentioned the code as 1,2,3 in the list and 3,4,5 in DataTable. But in comment you are trying to add 1,2,3 in both list as well as DataTable, hence you are getting 1 : x 2 : y 3 : z. Please populate dataTable as below and try.
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("code", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("value", typeof(string));
dt.Rows.Add("3", "a");
dt.Rows.Add("4", "b");
dt.Rows.Add("5", "c");

Comment: Sarwar, you spot it right. thanks so much for your advice and help. One last thing, I want to extend my select to display item from d as per suggestion by Peter like select new { l.code, l.name, d.value }; but the IDE intellisence does not recognize it

Comment: It should be d.Field<string>("value") Instead of d.value...

Comment: Sarwar, thanks for continuing to provide your answer to my question. I have tried yours and intellisense still does not recognize it d.Field<string>("value")

select new { l.code, l.name, d.Field<string>("value")};

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what your required output is but it looks as if you are correctly getting the only common records. You could extend your `select` to

```
select new { l.code, l.name, d.value }
```

Which would give all the data/columns from both tables.

```
code name value
==== ==== =====
  3    z     a
```

Comment: Hi Peter,

the query result above shows as:

1 : x

2 : y

3 : z

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var ld = from l in lst
         join d in dt.Cast <DataRow>() on l.code equals d["code"].ToString()
         select new { l.code, l.name };
```

Comment: Hi Moha, the intellisence complaints by saying 
DataTable does not contain a definition for 'Cast' and the best extension method overlooad 'EnumerableRowCollectionExtensions.Cast<DataRow>(EnumerableRowCollection)' requires a receiver of type 'EnumerableRowCollection'

Answer (score 0):

SO you have a List and a DataTable. You don't plan to use the Values of the DataTable, only the Codes.

You want to keep those List items, that have a Code that is also a code in the DataTable.

If you plan to use your DataTable for other things than just for this problem, My advice would be to first create a procedure to convert your DataTable into an enumerable sequence.

This way you can add LINQ statements, not only for this problem, but also for other problems.

Let's create an extension method for your DataTable that converts the data into the items that are in the DataTable. See [extension methods demystified.](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

Alas, I don't know what's in your DataTable, let's assume that your DataTable contains `Orders`

```
class CustomerOrder
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int CustomerId {get; set;}

    public int Code {get; set;}
    public string Value {get; set;} 
    ...
}
```

The extension method that extends functionality of class DataTable:

```
public static IEnumerable<Order> ToCustomerOrders(this DataTable table)
{
    return table.AsEnumerable().Select(row => new CustomerOrder
    {
        Id = ...
        CustomerId = ...
        Code = ...
        Value = ...
     };
}
```

I'm not really familiar with DataTables, but you know how to convert the cells of the row into the proper value.

Usage:

```
DataTable table = ...
Int customerId = 14;

var ordersOfThisCustomer = table.ToCustomerOrders
    .Where(customerOrder => customerOrder.CustomerId == customerId)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

In words: convert the datatable into CustomerOrders, row by row, and check for every converted CustomerOrder whether it has a CustomerId equal to 14. Stop if found. return null if there is no such row.

Now that you've got a nice reusable procedure that is also easy to test, debug and change, we can answer your question.

> Given a DataTable with CustomerOrders, and a sequence of items that contain `Code` and `Name`, keep only those items from the sequence that have a Code that is also a Code in the DataTable.

```
var dataTable = ...   // your DataTable, filled with CustomerOrders.
var codeNames = ...   // your list with Codes and Names

var codesInDataTable = dataTable.ToCustomerOrders
    .Select(customerOrder => customerOrder.Code)
    .Distinct();
```

This will create an enumerable sequence that will convert your DataTable row by row and extract property Code. Duplicate Code values will be removed.

If Codes are unique, you don't need Distinct.

Note: the enumerable sequence is not enumerated yet!

```
var result = codeNames
    .Where(codeName => codesInDataTable.Contains(codeName.Code))
    .ToList();
```

In words: for every [Code, Name] combination in your list, keep only those [Code, Name] combinations that have a value for Code that is also in `codesInDataTable`.